# AWS and PuTTy. bad service request ssh-connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

When I tried to access my EC2 instance using Putty, I got as error saying "bad service request ssh-connection". What did I do wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Here is what I did.

1. Created a new instance with new key pair.
2. PuTTy gen converted pem file into ppk file.
3. In PuTTy, I set host name ec2-user@Public DNS(IPv4).
4. Under Connection-SSH-Auth, I browsed for the ppk file I got earlier.
5. I unchecked Display pre-authentication banner and checked Bypass authentication entirely.
6. Then hit open

I should be able to access Amazon Linux Terminal but I got error, "bad service request ssh-connection"

EDIT:
I am sorry if this question was off topic. Since AWS, AWS-EC2, and PuTTy were all legit categories, I thought I could ask questions about them.

Comment: In step 3, you don't need to include ec2-user in host name, only use your public DNS, remove ec2-user@

Comment: Im still having the same problem

Comment: Do reverse in step5, check pre-authentication and uncheck Bypass authentication

Comment: Do you have the 'Bypass authentication entirely' checked by any chance? if so, it should not be checked

Comment: it worked! Thanks guys. Video I watched had bypass authentication checked.

Comment: if you dont mind answering a few more questions, how does pricing work? If I want more RAM or GPU, do they charge only when my python script is running? or the whole time my instance is running.

Comment: With On-Demand instances, you pay for compute capacity by per hour or per second depending on which instances you run.

Comment: for example, p2.xlarge is $0.9/hour in my area. I launch an instance at 8 and then set up environment or edit my code and start running my script at 10. the code finished running at 13, then I terminate the instance at 14. I had the instance for 6 hours but I only ran my code for 3 hours. Do I get charged for $0.9/hr * 3hr = $2.7?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In step 3, remove ec2-user@ and only keep your public DNS.

In step 5, check pre-authentication and uncheck Bypass authentication.

Comment: This did work. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you Cyrus for the tip. I used a private IPV4 address to logon successfully.